# How to set handle-redirect in jersey 2

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

With Jersey 1.18, I was able to set this as below :

```
ApacheHttpClient4 apacheHttpClient4 = (ApacheHttpClient4) jerseyClient;
HttpClient httpClient = apacheHttpClient4.getClientHandler().getHttpClient();
httpClient.getParams().setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.handle-redirects", false);
```

How do I set this in Jersey 2 ?

I see that HttpParams are deprecated, but unable to figure out how do I use `org.apache.http.client.config` for this purpose.

Comment: Can you show the full code of how you are using the JERSEY client. If you are using the actual Jersey 2.0 [jersey-client](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html), following redirects the is default bevahior

Comment: Never mind I just read the code, and it looks like you want to set the redirect to false. For this you need to set the client property `ClientProperties.FOLLOW_REDIRECTS` to false, which is true by default

Comment: If you want to use the Apache connector, the property will still work the same. You can see the [test case with the Apache connector](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/connectors/apache-connector/src/test/java/org/glassfish/jersey/apache/connector/FollowRedirectsTest.java)

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work fine.